# Can I ask the Associate Editor of a journal for an update on a paper I refereed?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission

I wrote a referee report for a paper and recommended a minor revision. This was in December 2019 and I have not heard from the associate editor regarding the fate of this paper.

Is it inappropriate for me to request an update on the status of the paper? Whether it was rejected outright or whether a revision is in the making?

Comment: Why would you want to know?

Comment: So now the referees will be loading up the editor's mailbox with questions on the status of the paper? I never expect any further info on the paper from the editor. I've done the referee report and my part is over.

Comment: I am changing jobs and will not be able to review a revision of the paper if I have to wait much longer for it. In any case, I decided not to ask the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask sure.

But you may not get a response at all or just get a “it’s in progress” or “it is completed and published or not”. He/she may decide to give detail if they wish.